# Save configuration of pivottablejs in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, pivottable.js

I am using google Colab (Jupyter python notebook on a server) to run the pivot table.

This code:

```
pivot_ui(d1,outfile_path='pivottablejs.html')
HTML('pivottablejs.html')
```

Results in this blank pivot:
[image]

Which I can manipulate to get this desired chart:
[image]

But when I refresh the page it all goes back to the blank pivot. What I would like is to store the config of the desired chart so that I can get it back after a refresh.

I am aware that there are instructions on how to do this in [JavaScript](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#accessingsaving-pivottable-state), but I cannot figure out how to do this in a Jupyter notebook. Any ideas?

**Edit** It seems I am not the first to have tried: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/issues/34 and it is not possible with the current set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My hacky solution**

I rewrote part of the pivottablejs package to add a "copy config" button. I put this code in an earlier cell in by Jupyter notebook, so the function would be accessible later:

**Version for Google Colab:**

```
!pip install pivottablejs
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import IFrame
import json, io

TEMPLATE = u"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PivotTable.js</title>

        <!-- external libs from cdnjs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/pivot.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/pivot.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/d3_renderers.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/c3_renderers.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/export_renderers.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {font-family: Verdana;}
            .node {
              border: solid 1px white;
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              line-height: 12px;
              overflow: hidden;
              position: absolute;
              text-indent: 2px;
            }
            .c3-line, .c3-focused {stroke-width: 3px !important;}
            .c3-bar {stroke: white !important; stroke-width: 1;}
            .c3 text { font-size: 12px; color: grey;}
            .tick line {stroke: white;}
            .c3-axis path {stroke: grey;}
            .c3-circle { opacity: 1 !important; }
            .c3-xgrid-focus {visibility: hidden !important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                $("#output").pivotUI(
                    $.csv.toArrays($("#output").text())
                    , $.extend({
                        renderers: $.extend(
                            $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.d3_renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
                            ),
                        hiddenAttributes: [""]
                    } 
                    , {
                        onRefresh: function(config) {
                            var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
                            //delete some values which are functions
                            delete config_copy["aggregators"];
                            delete config_copy["renderers"];
                            //delete some bulky default values
                            delete config_copy["rendererOptions"];
                            delete config_copy["localeStrings"];
                            $("#output2").text(JSON.stringify(config_copy, undefined, 2));
                        }
                    }
                    , %(kwargs)s
                    , %(json_kwargs)s)
                ).show();
             });
        </script>
        <div id="output" style="display: none;">%(csv)s</div>

        <textarea id="output2"
        style="float: left; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity:0;" readonly>
        </textarea>

        <button onclick="copyTextFunction()">Copy settings</button>
        <script>
        function copyTextFunction() {
                    var copyText = document.getElementById("output2");
                    copyText.select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
"""


def pivot_cht_html(df, outfile_path = "pivottablejs.html", url="",
    width="100%", height="500",json_kwargs='',  **kwargs):
  with io.open(outfile_path, 'wt', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
      csv = df.to_csv(encoding='utf8')
      if hasattr(csv, 'decode'):
          csv = csv.decode('utf8')
      outfile.write(TEMPLATE %
            dict(csv=csv, kwargs=json.dumps(kwargs),json_kwargs=json_kwargs))
  
  IFrame(src=url or outfile_path, width=width, height=height)
  return HTML(outfile_path)
```

**Version for standard Jupyter notebook:**

```
#this is my custom version of pivottablejs, it allows you to save your analysis
!pip install pivottablejs
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import IFrame
import json, io

TEMPLATE = u"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PivotTable.js</title>

        <!-- external libs from cdnjs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/pivot.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/pivot.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/d3_renderers.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/c3_renderers.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pivottable/2.19.0/export_renderers.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {font-family: Verdana;}
            .node {
              border: solid 1px white;
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              line-height: 12px;
              overflow: hidden;
              position: absolute;
              text-indent: 2px;
            }
            .c3-line, .c3-focused {stroke-width: 3px !important;}
            .c3-bar {stroke: white !important; stroke-width: 1;}
            .c3 text { font-size: 12px; color: grey;}
            .tick line {stroke: white;}
            .c3-axis path {stroke: grey;}
            .c3-circle { opacity: 1 !important; }
            .c3-xgrid-focus {visibility: hidden !important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                $("#output").pivotUI(
                    $.csv.toArrays($("#output").text())
                    , $.extend({
                        renderers: $.extend(
                            $.pivotUtilities.renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.d3_renderers,
                            $.pivotUtilities.export_renderers
                            ),
                        hiddenAttributes: [""]
                    } 
                    , {
                        onRefresh: function(config) {
                            var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
                            //delete some values which are functions
                            delete config_copy["aggregators"];
                            delete config_copy["renderers"];
                            //delete some bulky default values
                            delete config_copy["rendererOptions"];
                            delete config_copy["localeStrings"];
                            $("#output2").text(JSON.stringify(config_copy, undefined, 2));
                        }
                    }
                    , %(kwargs)s
                    , %(json_kwargs)s)
                ).show();
             });
        </script>
        <div id="output" style="display: none;">%(csv)s</div>

        <textarea id="output2"
        style="float: left; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity:0;" readonly>
        </textarea>

        <button onclick="copyTextFunction()">Copy settings</button>
        <script>
        function copyTextFunction() {
                    var copyText = document.getElementById("output2");
                    copyText.select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
"""


def pivot_cht_ui(df, name, url="",
    width="100%", height="500",json_kwargs='',  **kwargs):
  print(name)
  outfile_path = name + '.html'
  with io.open(outfile_path, 'wt', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
      csv = df.to_csv(encoding='utf8')
      if hasattr(csv, 'decode'):
          csv = csv.decode('utf8')
      outfile.write(TEMPLATE %
            dict(csv=csv, kwargs=json.dumps(kwargs),json_kwargs=json_kwargs))
  
  return IFrame(src=url or outfile_path, width=width, height=height)
```

This enables you to make a chart as so (google colab version, slightly different for Jupyter notebook version):

```
pivot_cht_html(d1)
```

Which loads a blank chart which you can manually configure (below image is configured). Note the "copy settings" button:
[image]
If you press the button it copies a JSON of the config, which you can then put back into the charting function so that it runs your configured chart:

```
pivot_cht_html(d1,json_kwargs="""
{
  "derivedAttributes": {},
  "hiddenAttributes": [
    ""
  ],
  "hiddenFromAggregators": [],
  "hiddenFromDragDrop": [],
  "menuLimit": 500,
  "cols": [
    "weeks"
  ],
  "rows": [],
  "vals": [
    "resurrected_90d"
  ],
  "rowOrder": "key_a_to_z",
  "colOrder": "key_a_to_z",
  "exclusions": {},
  "inclusions": {},
  "unusedAttrsVertical": 85,
  "autoSortUnusedAttrs": false,
  "sorters": {},
  "inclusionsInfo": {},
  "aggregatorName": "Average",
  "rendererName": "Line Chart"
}
""")
```

This is far from ideal... Ideally this should be added to the pivottablejs package as a PR. If I get time I will try to do this!